# ScalaTest: Suites are being executed but no test cases are actually running?

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I am using the latest version of Play framework, along with the following test dependencies from by `build.sbt` file:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0",
"org.scalatestplus.play" % "scalatestplus-play_2.11" % "2.0.0-M1"
```

I have a base specification all of my test cases extend from. I return a `Future[Assertion]` in each one of my clauses, it looks like this:

```
trait BaseSpec extends AsyncWordSpec with TestSuite with OneServerPerSuite with MustMatchers with ParallelTestExecution
```

An example spec looks like this:

```
"PUT /v1/user/create" should {
    "create a new user" in {
      wsClient
        .url(s"http://localhost:${port}/v1/user")
        .put(Json.obj(
          "name" -> "username",
          "email" -> "email",
          "password" -> "hunter12"
        )).map { response => response.status must equal(201) }
    }
}
```

I decided to rewrite my current tests using the `AsyncWordSpec` provided by the newer version of `ScalaTest`, but when I run the test suite, this is the output that I get:

```
[info] UserControllerSpec:
[info] PUT /v1/user/create
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Starting application at 2016-11-13T01:29:12.161Z.
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Stopping application at 2016-11-13T01:29:12.416Z after 1s.
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Stopping application at 2016-11-13T01:29:12.438Z after 0s.
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Stopping application at 2016-11-13T01:29:12.716Z after 0s.
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Stopping application at 2016-11-13T01:29:13.022Z after 1s.
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 13 seconds, 540 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 4, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[success] Total time: 20 s, completed Nov 12, 2016 8:29:13 PM
```

All of my test classes are found, built, and seemingly run by the test runner when invoking `sbt test`. I have also tried using the IDEA test runner, and it reports `Empty Test Suite` under each one of my test classes. I have exhaustively attempted to RTFM but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. The synchronous versions of my tests are running totally fine.

EDIT 1: A friend suggested to attempt doing `whenReady() { /* clause */ }` on my `Future[WSResponse]`, but this too has failed.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem while using a test suite with multiple traits. I got it to work by removing all the other traits except for `AsyncFlatSpec`. I will add them back one at a time as I need them.

Comment: Removing `with MockitoFixture` made the tests run for me.

Comment: `MockFactory` (ScalaMock) was the problem for me. `Matchers`, `LoneElement` could be mixed in without any problems.

Comment: If you are using `AsyncFlatSpec`, then you must use `AsyncMockFactory` (instead of MockFactory). More info: https://scalamock.org/user-guide/integration/